# Print multi dimensional array onto excel sheet VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to have a for loop that takes my weeks and then another for loop that looks at my product to calculate the sales for this year, last year and then the difference. I am getting 0's for all of the weeks except for the current week, any idea what is wrong with my code? Thanks

```vba
Sub Weekly_Recap()
Dim h, d As Worksheet
Dim myarray(), answers() As Variant
'Dim week, datarange As Range
Dim D1, i As Long


Set h = Worksheets("Helper")
Set d = Worksheets("Data")


myarray = d.Range("P2:P51")

D1 = UBound(myarray, 1)

ReDim answers(1 To D1, 1 To 3)

For i = 1 To D1

    If myarray(i, 1) <= h.Range("A1") Then
    
    For j = 1 To 17
    
        answers(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(d.Range("G:G"), d.Range("B:B"), myarray(i, 1), d.Range("F:F"), h.Cells(j, 4))
        answers(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(d.Range("H:H"), d.Range("B:B"), myarray(i, 1), d.Range("F:F"), h.Cells(j, 4))
        answers(i, 3) = (answers(i, 1) - answers(1, 2)) / answers(i, 2)
    
            If h.Cells(j, 4) = "FLAVORED/FUNCTIONAL WATER" Then
                
                h.Range(h.Range("F2"), h.Range("F2").Offset(D1, 2)).Value = answers
                ElseIf h.Cells(j, 4) = "SALTY BAGGED/CANISTER SNACKS" Then
                
                h.Range(h.Range("K2"), h.Range("K2").Offset(D1, 2)).Value = answers
            End If
        Next j
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Screen shots of the Data and Helper tabs would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to understand what you are trying to do. When I tried to run your code in debug mode I noticed that line with offset is overwriting data in previous lines, and that is where you are getting all 0's. In lets say loop i = 1 and j = 1 you get some value, but in i = 1 and j = 2 you don't (sumif returns 0) and then you overwrite it in variable answers and then paste it in worksheet, at the end only last one has not been overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You need swap the loops to calculate all the weeks for each product in turn otherwise the figure for week1/product1 will be overwritten by week1/product2 then week1/product3 etc.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Sales()

    Dim arWeeks, NoOfWeeks As Long, iLastWeek As Long
    Dim rngSales1 As Range, rngSales2 As Range
    Dim rngWeek As Range, rngProduct As Range
    Dim iWeek As Long, sProduct As String
    Dim h As Worksheet, d As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long, i As Long
    
    Set h = Worksheets("Helper")
    Set d = Worksheets("Data")
    
    Set rngSales1 = d.Range("G:G")
    Set rngSales2 = d.Range("H:H")
    Set rngWeek = d.Range("B:B")
    Set rngProduct = d.Range("F:F")
    
    arWeeks = d.Range("P2:P51")
    iLastWeek = h.Range("A1").Value
    NoOfWeeks = UBound(arWeeks)
    
    ReDim answers(1 To NoOfWeeks, 1 To 3) 'yr1,yr2,diff
    
    For j = 1 To 17 ' products
        
        sProduct = h.Cells(j, 4)
    
        For i = 1 To NoOfWeeks ' weeks
        
            iWeek = arWeeks(i, 1)
            If iWeek <= iLastWeek Then
            
                With Application.WorksheetFunction
                   answers(i, 1) = .SumIfs(rngSales1, rngWeek, iWeek, rngProduct, sProduct)
                   answers(i, 2) = .SumIfs(rngSales2, rngWeek, iWeek, rngProduct, sProduct)
                End With
            
                If answers(i, 2) <> 0 Then
                   answers(i, 3) = (answers(i, 1) - answers(1, 2)) / answers(i, 2)
                End If
            
            End If
        Next i
        
        If sProduct = "FLAVORED/FUNCTIONAL WATER" Then
            h.Range("F2").Resize(NoOfWeeks, 3).Value = answers
        ElseIf sProduct = "SALTY BAGGED/CANISTER SNACKS" Then
            h.Range("k2").Resize(NoOfWeeks, 3).Value = answers
        End If
     
    Next j
    MsgBox "Done ", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how I can save my answers into arrays instead of putting them into a workbook? I am trying to order the data by weeks and have a recap that says something like, "Salty snacks  YoY % was above the last 13 weeks", do you know how I could have it do something like that? Thanks

Comment: @alexa answers() is a 2-D array (week,value) for one product, do you mean a 3D array (product,week,value) holding figures for more than one product ?  Presumably you want to compare for example YoY% week 23 with the YoY% in each week 10 to 22. Problem would be for the first 13 weeks of the year when you would have a compare previous and current years